# EasterEgg in Java

Tags: java

```
package easteregg;

import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

class MyCanvas extends JComponent {

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawOval (100, 20, 110, 160); 

  }
}

public class EasterEgg {
  public static void main(String[] a) {
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setBounds(30, 30, 300, 300);
    window.getContentPane().add(new MyCanvas());
    window.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

my problem is i dont know how to put lines inside the oval 
i want to make a easterEgg please help me

Comment: Theres a `drawLine` method for Graphics.

Comment: editted first line (`package`): was not in code block

Answer (score 0):

i have modified the paint method to draw one pattern please check the below code

```
 public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawOval (100, 20, 110, 160); 
    g.drawLine(120, 40, 140, 60);
    g.drawLine(140, 60, 150, 40);
    g.drawLine(150, 40, 170, 60);
    g.drawLine(170, 60, 190,40);

 }
```

and the output is
[image]

this is just a hint to draw lines but better to create one method which will draw that pattern form one end to other end of the oval